# Qt plugin && thread-safety

Tags: qt, plugins, thread-safety

I have several threads each of which loads the same plugin using QPluginLoader::staticInstances() call in constructor. Is it necessary to protect operating with plugin with mutexes / semaphores and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the functions of QPluginLoader are reentrant and you are operating on the same objects; so **yes** you need to synchronize on individual `QPluginLoader` objects at the very least.

`instance()` will also return a shared object which needs to be access in a thread-safe manner